# Grid-like layout for pages containing a graph and a table

Tags: tables, beamer, graphics, r, grid-typesetting

For an (R) analysis project I am working on I need to automatically generate reports containing graphs and tables that will later be reviewed by other people. I wrote my thesis in latex, but I never had to do layout-intensive parts. I want to a achieve a layout similar to this:

[image]

*(the horizontal lines are just for illustration, I don't need them in the document)*

In the ideal case, I would be able to define presets for three different kinds of pages that, I could define similar to beamer slides:

- 1/3rd top frame(graph), 2/3 bottom frame (table)
- 2/3rd top frame(graph), 1/3 bottom frame (table)
- full-page graph/table

The images/tables should not be able to screw up the grid, and in the worst case be cropped to the 'frames' they are in.

Is this even possible in latex?